# How to customize profile2 module profile edit form using template method?

Tags: 7, theming

How to customize the profile edit form of the [Profile2](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2) module using a  template?

Profile2 has the main profile (`admin/structure/profiles/manage/main`), and it is set to provide a separate page for editing profiles (`profile-main/1/edit`).

In Drupal 7, for a content type such as *faq*, I can use a template to customized its edit form.

In `template.php`, I am using the following code:

```
function MYTHEME_theme(&$existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
      'faq_node_form' => array(
      'arguments' => array('form' => NULL),
      'template' => 'node--faq--edit',
      'render element' => 'form',
  ),
  );
}
```

I then create `node--faq--edit.tpl.php`, where I can customize it.

What is the equivalent method I could use for a Profile2 profile edit form?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `form_id` as theme key in `hook_theme()`, which is `user_profile_form` in the case.

```php
function MYTHEME_theme(&$existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'user_profile_form' => array(
      // …
    ),
  );
}
```

See [Theme Profile2 Form](https://www.drupal.org/node/1895210), a support request opened for the Profile2 module.